# git rebase --onto with EGit, no support?

Tags: eclipse, git, egit, feature-branch

I have a typical use case working with feature branches and Git, as follows:

[image]

I want to rebase my feature branch onto master, without applying the commits from the branch "1.24", I have managed to do this from the command line specifying all the parameters, but I still cant find a graphical way to do this from eclipse.

What do you do on these cases? It is happening the same to me with merging, I believe this is a very common scenario on GitFlow workflow.

Answer (score 0):

While your `feature` branch is checked out. Select "Rebase on" in context menu of `master` branch. That will rebase target branch with all commits that are not on master. That would be a typical use of rebase, not exactly what --onto does, however.

**Update**:

To select just a partial branch you can use interactive rebase (select "Interactive rebase" in context menu of target branch). It is very quick to use, so you can use it instead of --onto, which I think is not implemented in EGit in any form.

Comment: This is what I have done, but then it would apply also commit A and commit B. I only want to apply commit E on top of the master.

Comment: Sorry, did not understand your question fully. I would use interactive rebase which has a nice UI for selecting interesting commits. Try "Rebase interactive" on the context menu instead. Here is some [documentation](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Interactive_Rebase).